# Dell XPS 9370 blank screen on wakeup after Dell TB16 docking station unplug/disconnect (Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, dell, hibernate, wakeup

I bought a new **Dell XPS 9730** (Intel UHD Graphics 620) along with **Dell TB16** docking station, and everything works perfectly, only when I disconnect it from TB16 docking station while in hibernation - **when I wake it up, laptop turns on, but the built-in screen stays dark**.

**When connected to dock, laptop lid is closed at all times and output is shown to 2 external Dell monitors** (1920x1200 and 1920x1080). But when disconnected from port, the output should be shown only to built-in display of course. **When I wake system up from hibernation without changing output source, everything works fine**. Also if I restart the laptop after unplugging, everything works fine. I get the same behavior on 16.04 and 18.04.

Xrandr specs (`xrandr -q`): [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLumT.png)

I was playing a little with hibernate post script like `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/update-displays`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Reset monitors in case laptop was detached

set -e

echo "Checking enabled monitors"

if [ "$2" = "hibernate" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        post)
        if [xrandr -q|grep DP-1-2|egrep -v disconnected] && [xrandr -q|grep DP-2-2|egrep -v disconnected]; then
        echo "Enabling built-in monitor"
        xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto
        fi
            ;;
    esac
fi
```

But without success... Maybe some mistakes in the scripts? **I suspect that xrandr doesn't refresh on wakeup and it uses "old" configuration still.** Is there any other way to refresh it? Or to adjust previous post script somehow?

Everything else works perfectly and I like the laptop a lot, only this issue is a little frustrating, since I have to restart the system everytime I plug/unplug it from dock.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.. I had wrong event filter on `$2` parameter (hibernate or hybrid-sleep). I also simplified the script in case anyone else finds it handy:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Reset xrandr at wakeup in case any display setup change was made

case "$2" in
  hibernate|suspend)
    case "$1" in
      post)
        xrandr --auto
        echo "System waking up from -$2- at $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')" >> /tmp/update-displays.txt
      ;;
    esac
  ;;
esac
```

In Ubuntu 18.04 put in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` i.e. `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/update-displays` and set correct permissions (mine was 755).